# Opening and closing quantity in issue at SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

previous record of closing balance is next record opening balance 
closing balance is sum of opening balance and used quantity

Here is previous output:

[image: previous table]

Here is Expected output

[image]

Comment: You need an additional column indicating the order that this happened in. Database don't have an inherent "order" unless you sepcifically have a column that defines it. It makes more sense to have this calc occur when the usedqty arrives in the database. It doesn't really make sense to work this out after the fact. Or are you just happy to have a query that you can run to get this result? Again, you need a column that indicates the order of transactions

Comment: Thanks Nick 
But opening balance of First record received after some time.
that is the issue 
Can i declare that one as variable (opening balance of First record)

Comment: Oh sorry, I see there is a rownumber column after all. So a late arriving openign balance clarifies that you do need to calc it afterwards. Why don't you try @zealous answer below

Comment: lag avialable in SQL 2012 after onwards but i need solution in SQL 2008

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using `lag()`. Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb43ebd672099e8092d7e3bfde4a4a21).

```
select
    contname,
    contcode,
    usedqty,
    coalesce(lag(closing) over (order by rn), opening) as opening,
    coalesce(lag(closing) over (order by rn) + usedqty, closing) as closing
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Ancient, unsupported versions of SQL Server, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*,
       (running.running_used + running.running_opening - usedqty) as opening,
       (running.running_used + running.running_opening) as closing
from t outer apply
     (select sum(tprev.usedqty) as running_used,
             sum(opening) as running_opening
      from t tprev
      where tprev.rn <= t.rn
     ) running.;
```